# Cart block not updating codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have this controller:

```html
<?php
class Cart extends CI_Controller{
  public $paypal_data = '';
  public $tax;
  public $shipping;
  public $total = 0;
  public $grand_total;

  /*
  *Cart Index
  */
  public function index(){
    //Load view
    $data['main_content'] = 'cart';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
  }

  /*
  *Add To Cart
  */
  public function add(){
    //Item data
    $data = array(
      'id'=> $this->input->post('item_number'),
      'qty'=> $this->input->post('qty'),
      'price'=> $this->input->post('price'),
      'name'=> $this->input->post('title'),
    );
    //print_r($data);die();

    //Insert Into cart-block
    $this->cart->insert($data);

    redirect('products');
  }
  }
```

And I have the view file which uses this controller:

```html
<div class="cart-block">
  <form action="cart/update" method="post">
    <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>Item Description</th>
        <th style="text-align:right">Item Price</th>
      </tr>
      <?php $i = 1; ?>
      <?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items) : ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $i. '[rowid]'; ?>" value="<?php echo $items['rowid']; ?>" />
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $i.'[qty]'; ?>" value="<?php echo $items['qty']; ?>" maxlength="3" size= "5"</td>
          <td><?php echo $items['name']; ?></td>
          <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['price']); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php $i++; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td class="right" style="text-align:right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total()); ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <p><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Update Cart</button>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="cart">Go To Cart</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default panel-list">
  <div class="panel-heading panel-jeading-dark">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
      Categories
    </h3>
  </div>

  <!--List group -->
  <ul class="list-group">
    <?php foreach(get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/category/<?php echo $category->id; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
```

I apologize that I can't show you the actual website because it's not online but based on the above snippets can any point out an error in the view file or controller that causes the shopping cart not to update?

I'm following a video tutorial but it seems I'm doing something wrong. Here is the video: https://youtu.be/ajt_DJMS5FM?t=13m45s

Comment: You don't have **update** method in **Cart** controller, do you mean not adding?

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is cart/update your function in the controller is add?

Change the form action to cart/add. Or write an cart/update function.

Comment: skip through to here https://youtu.be/ajt_DJMS5FM?t=925 it explains the controller function.

Comment: Yeah, I've watched it over and over again now which is why it doesn't make sense. I also added the cart update function but that is affected by the same issue.

Comment: Check if it's going on the right controller, if yes, then maybe the setup of model is the problem

Comment: @ChristianEsperar how would you design it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change the Form Action  **action="cart/update"** to

```
action="<?php echo base_url();?>cart/add" and apply die(); and test it
```

Comment: Where do I apply die(); ?

Comment: Okay so I applied the die(); just after the array, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

load the cart library in controller

```
$this->load->library('cart');
```